# How Rust turn Vec<Vec<char>> to Vec<String>?

Tags: rust

For a example:

```
let record: Vec<Vec<char>> = vec![vec!['.'; 10]; 10];
let example: Vec<String> = record.into_iter().into_iter().collect::<String>().collect::<Vec<String>>();
```

this doesn't work.
how to trans record to example.

Answer (score 4):

You need to iterate and collect each of them to a `String`:

```rust
let example: Vec<String> = record
    .iter()
    .map(|v| v.iter().collect::<String>())
    .collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=785341c769cecb9279f4b64c89cd22cc)

Comment: Though it should be noted that for the specific code above `".".repeat(10)` would be a lot simpler, and probably more efficient.